# Anttweakbar glfw3 OpenGL 3.2 not drawing

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3, glfw

I'm having some trouble using AntTweakBar with modern opengl (dynamic pipeline) and glfw3. I'm using some shaders and i'm pretty sure the problem is something about the camera or the shaders.
The keyboard shortcuts are working but I don't have the fancy window I should have :(

Here is the source

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#if __cplusplus <= 199711L
#define nullptr NULL
#endif
#include <cmath>
#include <AntTweakBar.h>

const GLchar *vxShaderSrc = R"(
#version 150 core

in vec2 position;
in vec4 color;
uniform vec2 offset;

out vec4 Color;

void main()
{
    Color = color;
    gl_Position = vec4(position+offset, 0.0, 1.0);
}
)";

const GLchar *fragShaderSrc = R"(
#version 150 core
in vec4 Color;
out vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    outColor = Color;
}
)";

inline void TwEventMouseButtonGLFW3(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mods)
{TwEventMouseButtonGLFW(button, action);}
inline void TwEventMousePosGLFW3(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{TwMouseMotion(int(xpos), int(ypos));}
inline void TwEventMouseWheelGLFW3(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{TwEventMouseWheelGLFW(yoffset);}
inline void TwEventKeyGLFW3(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{TwEventKeyGLFW(key, action);}
inline void TwEventCharGLFW3(GLFWwindow* window, int codepoint)
{TwEventCharGLFW(codepoint, GLFW_PRESS);}
inline void TwWindowSizeGLFW3(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{TwWindowSize(width, height);}


int main()
{
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cerr<<"Error initializing glfw...\n";
        return 1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
#ifdef __APPLE__ // TODO is it ok to use it on Windows and Linux?
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);

    TwBar *bar;
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
    if (!window) {
        std::cerr<<"Error creating window...\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 2;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL); // can be GLFW_CURSOR_HIDDEN

     // Initialize AntTweakBar
    TwInit(TW_OPENGL, NULL);

    // Create a tweak bar
    bar = TwNewBar("TweakBar");
    TwWindowSize(800, 600);
    int wire = 0;
    float bgColor[] = { 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.4f };
    TwDefine(" GLOBAL help='This example shows how to integrate AntTweakBar with GLFW and OpenGL.' "); // Message added to the help bar.
    // Add 'wire' to 'bar': it is a modifable variable of type TW_TYPE_BOOL32 (32 bits boolean). Its key shortcut is [w].
    TwAddVarRW(bar, "wire", TW_TYPE_BOOL32, &wire, 
               " label='Wireframe mode' key=w help='Toggle wireframe display mode.' ");
    // Add 'bgColor' to 'bar': it is a modifable variable of type TW_TYPE_COLOR3F (3 floats color)
    TwAddVarRW(bar, "bgColor", TW_TYPE_COLOR3F, &bgColor, " label='Background color' ");

    // Set GLFW event callbacks
    // - Redirect window size changes to the callback function WindowSizeCB
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, (GLFWwindowposfun)TwWindowSizeGLFW3);

    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback(window, (GLFWmousebuttonfun)TwEventMouseButtonGLFW3);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, (GLFWcursorposfun)TwEventMousePosGLFW3);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, (GLFWscrollfun)TwEventMouseWheelGLFW3);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (GLFWkeyfun)TwEventKeyGLFW3);
    glfwSetCharCallback(window, (GLFWcharfun)TwEventCharGLFW3);


    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_NO_ERROR) {
        std::cerr<<"Error initializing GLEW...\n";
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    std::cout << "Created vertex array with id " << vao << "\n";
    glBindVertexArray(vao); // save the calls of vertexattribpointer and others, MUST BE before the EBO

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo); // Generate 1 buffer
    std::cout << "Created Arrray with id " << vbo << "\n";
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.0f, 1.f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.f, 1.0f, 1.f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.f,
        // some extra for elements testing
        0.0f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.f, // Vertex 1: Red
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.f, // Vertex 2: Green
        -0.25f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.f, 1.0f, 1.f // Vertex 3: Blue
    };

    // size is actually sizeof(float)*vertices.length
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // elemets buffer object allows to use the same vertex multiple times
    GLuint elements[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3
    };
    GLuint ebo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
    std::cout << "Created elements with id " << ebo << "\n";
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // create shaders
    GLint status; // for error checking
    char buffer[512];
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vxShaderSrc, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status != GL_TRUE) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, buffer);
        std::cerr<<"Error in shader: "<<buffer<<"\n";
    }

    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragShaderSrc, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status != GL_TRUE) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, buffer);
        std::cerr<<"Error in shader: "<<buffer<<"\n";
    }

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

    // bind the output
    // this is the actual output by default
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");

    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram); // called everytime somethign change for the shader
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6*sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          6*sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2*sizeof(GLfloat)));

    GLint uniPos = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "offset");

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);

        glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, wire?GL_LINE:GL_FILL );

        float time =  (float)glfwGetTime();

        // Clear the screen to black
        glClearColor(bgColor[0], bgColor[1], bgColor[2], 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUniform2f(uniPos, cos(time*4.f)*0.5f, sin(time*4.f)*0.5f);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); // we can share vertex and we specify indexes

        glUniform2f(uniPos, 0.f, 0.f);
        // Draw tweak bars
        //glUseProgram(0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        TwDraw();
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        //glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        //glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // clean up
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    TwTerminate();
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

You can compile the code with

```
g++ src/main.cpp -std=c++11 -DGLEW_STATIC -lGLEW -lglfw3 -framework OpenGL -lAntTweakBar
```

or

```
mingw32-g++.exe main.cpp -std=c++11 -DGLEW_STATIC -lglew32 -lglfw3 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lAntTweakBar
```

Adapt as needed

Comment: You cannot compile the code using the second command, that is a conflict of linkage. You should be using `glew32s` with `-DGLEW_STATIC`, not `glew32`.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman That's with MVS not with mingw

Comment: I suppose you *could* compile glew yourself and call the static library `glew32`, but if you download it in binary form from the SourceForge site, then `glew32` is the dynamic library and `glew32s` is the static and this will not link.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I actually did compile glew myself. Do you think it may change soemthing for AntTweakBar?

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with your problem. I was just pointing out that your build instructions for Windows were missing an important detail (the fact that you built GLEW yourself instead of using the pre-built library, which uses different names).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman ok, thank you. Now I'm actually compiling it, it's much easier.

Comment: I foudn the solution: Sin ce I'm using CORE:

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);

I need to change this

    TwInit(TW_OPENGL, NULL);

by

    TwInit(TW_OPENGL_CORE, NULL);

The problem is that some patches need to be done on OS X. I'm going to correct it and add a pull request on brew

Comment: @Posva If you solved it, be sure to answer your own question.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I cannot mark my answer as good because it's not voted enough >.<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution: Since I'm using CORE:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
```

I need to change this `TwInit(TW_OPENGL, NULL);` to  `TwInit(TW_OPENGL_CORE, NULL);`
I had to patch the homebrew AntTweakBar version to make this work